# Modular Exponentiation Speedup

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Is it possible to speedup modular exponentiation $a^e\bmod n$ with large $n$, $e$ when the complete factorization of $n-1$ is known?

Comment: Is modular exponentiation the bottle neck of some (your) algorithm?

Comment: What does $n-1$ have to do with exponentiation for a general $n$? There exists a *fast exponentiation algorithm*,  but it does not depend on $n-1$ in general – except if $n$ is prime.

Comment: I know that when $n$ is prime, $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, according to Fermat's Little Theorem. I was just wondering if the factorization of n-1 can help with the calculation if $n$ is composite. Theoretical interest.